# sed HTML </ >tags

Tags: html, bash, sed

I would like to remove all the HTML tags  from the grep result when parsing HTML page so the result would be plain text,
Like for example when parsing phpinfo to get only PHP version instead of the full line including HTML tags:

```
$curl -i http://piscina.tienda/phpinfo.php | grep 'PHP Version' | head -1 
 href="http://www.php.ne.... alt="PHP logo" /></a><h1 class="p">PHP Version 5.5.33</h1>
```

While I would like to get only "PHP Version 5.5.33" as result.

I have tried following sed patterns:

```
sed -e 's/<.*>//g'
sed -e 's/^<.*>$//g'
```

But the result is full HTML code or all blank (all output is replaced).
Could you please tell if it's possible to remove only HTML tags in this case with sed or there would better be used some other operator in this case? Or the problem is with pattern?

Thanks in advance for any tips !

Comment: `sed -e 's/<\/?[^>]*>//g'` ?

Comment: The problem is with the pattern. Also it is quite easy in this particular case but in general regex should not be used to parse html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the tips everybody. After some additional research, the following pattern did the trick:

sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'

```
$ curl -is http://piscina.tienda/phpinfo.php | grep 'PHP Version' | head -1 | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
PHP Version 5.5.33
```

Hope that it will help someone in future.

Comment: Mark this answer as correct to make it easier for people to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, marked it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not manipulate XML data using line-oriented tools like `sed`. Use XML-aware tools like `xmlstarlet` instead. In this case, this might do what you want:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//text()'
```

Comment: I don't think XML-aware tools help for HTML as HTML is unlikely to be valid XML. (I realised this when I tried using xml-sed to alter HTML files.)
I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

By default regular expression are greedy, they will search for the biggest match. Add a `?` to the `*` (`'s/<.*?>//g'`) to make the matching process lazy.

Comment: sed doesn't support non-greedy regex though

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `sed`, just use the `parameter expansion`. Here is the code:

```
#save the first line into a variable
line='href="http://www.php.ne.... alt="PHP logo" /></a><h1 class="p">PHP Version 5.5.33</h1>'
tempstr=${line%<*}
result=${tempstr##*>}
echo "$result"
```

Output:

```
PHP Version 5.5.33
```

And if you want to keep those into a script, you can save the string by:

```
line=$(curl -i http://piscina.tienda/phpinfo.php | grep 'PHP Version' | head -1)
```

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thank you, never considered using an actual script although, wanted it to be just a command. However, I think it may be useful in future =)